# Is CHAN_MOBILE available with Asterisk 13?

Tags: asterisk, voip, pbx

I am compiling Asterisk 13, and when I have to `make menuselect`, it looks like it is unavailable. Am I right or it's included by default? What is the trick?

Here it is the menuselect image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After installing bluetooth driver it worked.
Solved.